# Extract a 10-bit integer from an ArrayBuffer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, bluetooth, arraybuffer

I'm building a bluetooth app with Ionic and its bluetooth serial plugin that reads 3 bytes from a heart-rate monitor according to [this](http://bitalino.com/datasheets/REVOLUTION_MCU_Block_Datasheet.pdf) scheme.

The [plugin] returns the data as an ArrayBuffer which contains a 10-bit integer spread over two bytes. I'm not sure how to extract those 10-bits and convert them to an integer, could someone help me out?

Edit:
This is the data structure from the pdf:

> While in live or simulated mode, the BITalino (r)evolution firmware streams the acquired data
>   in real time, formatted as a structured sequence of bits corresponding to:
>
> CRC: 4-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) code, useful for the evaluation of the data
>   packet consistency on the receiver.
>
> S: 4-bit sequential number generated by the firmware to identify the packet, which can be
>   used on the receiver to detect packet loss.
>
> O1 & O2: State of the digital output ports O1 & O2 on the device.
>
> I1 & I2: State of the digital input ports I1 & I2 on the device.
>
> A1-A6: Digital code produced by the ADC for the voltage at the corresponding analog input
>   ports A1-A6; the first four channels arrive with 10-bit resolution (ranging from 0-1023) while
>   the last two arrive with 6-bit (ranging from 0-63)

And the diagram:
[Bits diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBV7q.png)

Cheers,

Jared

Comment: Can you copy the relevant parts (unsigned / signed / two-complement integer etc.) from that PDF into your question? I don't understandt how that plugin reads 3 bytes but returns only a 2 bytes array buffer containing a 10-bit integer.

Comment: I have edited. I'm trying to extract A6 which is the heart rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read that chart right the data is byte[1]'s lower 4 bits combined with byte[0]'s higher 6 bits;

`// (buffer[1] - 0) & 0x0f) // get the 4 bits from byte 1
// (((buffer[0] - 0) & 0xfc) << 2) // get the 6 bits from byte 0 and shift over twice
result = ((buffer[1] - 0) & 0x0f) + ( ((buffer[0] - 0) & 0xfc) << 2 )`

Do you have a sample of what the byte buffer look likes?

Well, to better understand the 0x stuff, we need to look at the diagram in a bit more detail.

The first 4 bits are on byte 1 and specifically bits 0-3.  Bits 0-3 are 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15 or 0x0f.  I could have said (buffer[1] - 0) & 15), but using the hex notation 0x0f looks cleaner and kinda mirrors the data.

And for the data in byte 0, its from bits 2-7, which added together equal 252 or 0xfc.  Now the issue with this data is it starts on bit 2 and the data from byte 1 ends on bit 3.  We need to shift the bits, so they start on bit 4 and don't have any overlap.  With the bits shifted, we can add the two numbers together and get the combined number.

And if you need to know, I subtract 0 all over the place, because that forces JavaScript to treat the operations as numbers and not try to perform string math.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still wish I fully understood all the bit shifting and 0x00 notation but this looks to have worked. Much appreciated!

Comment: _“I subtract 0 all over the place, because that forces JavaScript to treat the operations as numbers”_ — then use `+buffer[1]`, which is shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `read` function and then you should do what @Michael Fuller pointed out. I would write it that way (**Edit**):

```
let array = new Int8Array(3);
bluetoothSerial.read(function(data) {
    array[0] = (data >> 16) & 0xff;
    array[1] = (data >> 8) & 0xff;
    array[2] = data & 0xff;
}); 

var bits6 = parseInt(array[0] & 0xfc);
bits6 <<= 2;
//0xfc=1111 1100, 0x0f=0000 1111
var decodedInteger = bits6 + parseInt(array[1] & 0x0f);
```